# No USB ports work

Tags: usb, bios

Got this computer used, so I don't know its history. It has 6 USB ports on the motherboard, plus 2 on the front panel. All of them display the same behavior: the power works, but there is no data transfer (So you can charge things off of them, but the computer doesn't recognize a device pluged in)

I added a PCI graphics card that I know works in another computer, and it displayed the same behavior which is very weird. The one PS2 port works, and I can get in to bios with the keyboard. I have tried resetting bios already, but nothing helps. Any suggestions?

**Edit:**

Specs:

Motherboard: asus p8h61-m le
OS: Ubuntu 12.04, but this doesn't matter because mouse should work in bios too, but doesn't.
Mouse: Tried many working USB mice. None work

**Edit 2:**
2 years later it occurs to me that it's possible this is a CPU connection error. Things like this can happen if some pins aren't making good contact. Haven't tested this hypothesis yet, but in case anyone else comes looking, you might try re-seating the CPU.

Comment: It's possible that the USB host controller is dead.

Comment: @Mokubai if the usb controller was dead, would this also affect a newly added working PCI card?

Comment: PCI or PCIe? Difficult to know for sure how it could affect it. Could be something further upstream. It's possible that this is simply a BIOS misconfiguration issue that somehow they turned off USB and disabled external graphics, or it could be any number of odd hardware failures.

Comment: Some firmwares do have a setting to turn off USB under the "Security" page.

Comment: PCI card. I've reset the bios, and the USB settings are all enabled.

Comment: So presumably a USB keyboard works?

Comment: ah, should have specified. No USB device works. I'm currently using a PS/2 keyboard

Comment: Sorry, just re-read the question and saw that. Disabled in the BIOS was my hope, but I suspect it's a hardware failure. PCI and USB could hang off a failed controller hub. I'm not a Linux guy, but the output of `lspci` would tell us whether the USB/PCI is appearing at all...

Comment: one of the lines on lspci is usb controller: intel corporation 6 series/c200.... Also, on the POST screen, 2 usb hubs are detected

Comment: It's now occoring to me that when I first booted the computer, the power supply had issues (would start up for a second, then shut down and reboot, or just start blinking the power light rapidly like it kept loosing power). I have since replaced the PSU. Could the failing one have somehow damaged the usb ports?

Answer (score 2):

On a PC mainboard, USB ports are powered from +5VSB (standby voltage) of the system PSU. This particular pwer rail is not powwrful, typicaly 2A. If the standby voltage is flaky, the computer will reset/reboot randomly, since the power-button logic is powered from the same standby voltage. So you need first to check if your PSU can supply reasonable power.

1. Get an old USB cable, cut it open, and put a 10-ohm load between black and red wire. The voltage should remain at 5V +-0.5V
2. To check if the USB controller any good, boot into BIOS configuration state, and attach a USB keyboard. If it works in parallel with your PS/2 keyboard, then at least UHCI root hub is working. Also attach a USB pen drive, formatted as FAT32 on a Windows machine, not with some Linux stuff . It also should appear in some BIOS area, as a bootable device or something.
3. If this works, the problem is in your Linux misconfiguration. Try to boot from a standalone CD Knoppix, or from Hiren's Boot CD.

If nothing works, try to completely reset the BIOS. This is the last resort. Remove the BIOS (coin) battery, and short the battery terminals for 10-20 seconds. Then reboot, load "safe defaults", and start over.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't believe any of this helps. They are all quite good suggestions, but I have tried a separate PSU, and had the same issue. A USB keyboard doesn't work in BIOS, nor is a USB detected. I have already reset the cmos multiple times with no luck.

Comment: @Blaine, fine, but is there a steady +5V on USB ports, under reasonable load?

Comment: that's the odd thing: Depends on the device. Charging a phone, or plugging in a webcam with a solid light: yes. A laser mouse however flashes once when plugged in and then becomes unresponsive

Comment: @Blaine, what do you mean "webcam with a solid light"? Does the webcam work? How solid is "solid light"? Charging a phone is also not an engineering measure of port capability. 20mA will give you a pretty solid light too. Seriously, can you measure the VBUS output at 10 Ohms load?

Comment: haha, ok. solid light is very solid, but the webcam (like all other usb devices plugged in to the computer) doesn't function. I'll try to get my hands on a USB cable and 10 ohm resistor and report back

Comment: @Blaine Did you try to boot into "Mini-XP" with Hiren's Boot CD? Look into device manager? Look if USBView.exe can see any USB roots?

Comment: It doesn't work in bios, or a linux live cd. Stands to reason, that it won't work in XP either. The problem is something to do with firmware or hardware, not the OS

Comment: @Blaine, the question is if some other software sees any USB-related hardware, not if it works or else. I don't know how Linux manages error reporting, or how it access the PCI configuration space. On Windows you will see something in Device Manager. Or not. BIOS and OS are independent, nearly. Did you try to upgrade/downgrade the current BIOS/UEFI firmware?

Comment: Havn't tried a bios update yet, but I was considering it. Don't have an XP disk at the moment, but i'll try to get one. What I can say is that lspci on linux does see a usb host controller

Comment: Ok, so an update: the mouse that I was using to troubleshoot is in fact, broken- some short internally (ugh). The usb ports are still dead, but this rules out any issues with power, as all other devices are powered normally.